# why am i getting segmentation fault core dumped?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, string-literals

i'm getting segmentation fault core dumped when im using strtok at the next code part. the code is getting debugged but when I run it I get the segmentation fault. How can I fix it?

```
struct{ char *name;
void(*func)(void);
}cmd[]={
{"read_cm",read_cm},
{"NA",NULL}
};
int d;
char *s="_\n";
  char *token2;
  for(d=0;cmd[d].func!=NULL;d++)
   {
   token2=strtok((cmd[d].name),s);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: When you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it actually *compiles*.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Also please use a debugger to locate where the crash happens in your code, and check the values of all involved variables when the crash happens. Make sure they are valid. And if you still can't figure it out, then include all that information in your question.

Comment: `cmd[d]name` is invalid syntax, you're missing a `.`.

Answer (score 3):

You may not modify a string literal. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

The standard C function `strtok` tries to insert a terminating zero while splitting a string into substrings.

To resolve the problem use a character array instead of the pointer `name`. Or allocate memory dynamically and copy a string to the allocated memory pointed to by the pointer `name`.

For example

```
struct
{ 
    char name[8];
    void(*func)(void);
} cmd[] = 
{
    { "read_cm", read_cm },
    { "NA", NULL }
};
```

Another approach is to use standard C functions `strcspn` and `strspn` instead of `strtok` to find substrings.

Comment: How did you come to know this? `cmd[d]name` is a syntax error, at best, there's no attempt to modify literal that actually executes. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think it is just a typo.

Comment: `You may not`...well, you __must__ not, unless you're ok causing UB in your code.. :)

Comment: I just fixed it, the typo was in here not in my code. im still getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Esmo What did you do to try to resolve it, based on what Vlad said in this answer ?

Comment: I fixed the typo to cmd[d].name but im still getting the segmentation fault.